# Trouble pinging LTE-device using IPv6

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, iot, lte, ppp

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi with an attached LTE Hat as an IoT device.
Currently I have managed to use ppp to get the LTE modem working. I've got IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and it is possible to ping from the device and to send data to an MQTT broker. At the end it would be fine to be able to log into the device using ssh. But currently I have trouble to ping the device or to get a working ssh connection to it over ppp.

I assume that something with the routing might be wrong. For this reason I post the current routing table of the IPv6:

```
route -6n
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    256 2     0 lo
2003:f5:cf00:1700::/64         ::                         U    202 3     0 eth0
2a02:3037:414:b1d4::/64        ::                         UA   256 1     0 ppp0
fe80::de6:3cd1:5bc0:1436/128   ::                         U    256 1     0 ppp0
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:beb8/128  ::                         U    256 1     0 ppp0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 eth0
::/0                           fe80::464e:6dff:fe5d:e7fc  UG   202 2     0 eth0
::/0                           fe80::de6:3cd1:5bc0:1436   UGDAe 1024 1   0 ppp0
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   6     0 lo
2003:f5:cf00:1700:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:a761/128 ::              Un   0   3     0 eth0
2003:f5:cf00:1700:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:549f/128 ::               Un   0   5    0 eth0
2a02:3037:414:b1d4:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:beb8/128 ::             Un   0   2     0 ppp0
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:a761/128  ::                         Un   0   4     0 eth0
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:beb8/128  ::                         Un   0   3     0 ppp0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 3     0 ppp0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     0 lo
```

The following commands fail (if entered on a different device ...)

```
ping -6 2a02:3037:414:b1d4:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:beb8
ssh 2a02:3037:414:b1d4:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:beb8
```

Would be nice if someone could give me a hint.
Thanks